# Help with making biomes and cities with procedural generation

Tags: procedural-generation, blueprints, unreal-5, noise

I'm working on a game in Unreal Engine 5 with Blueprints and the [Fast Noise plugin](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/fast-noise-generator?sessionInvalidated=true).

I've been having trouble getting the biomes and cities set up. I'm not fully sure how to make the biomes affect the terrain and structures that spawn. If anyone knows how I could go about this or any tutorials that don't involve rewriting all the generation code, it would be a great help.

Tutorial I used to make the code: [Terrain generation for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ASgfwzNvL8&list=PLyL5ZNukfVqskz_OkMdrLamiYg1sITyic&index=1)

Comment: You probably won't get an answer to everything one may want to do with biomes and cities in a single StackExchange answer — each one is a huge topic in its own right. Try to **edit your question** to explain one specific thing you want to do. You may find once you have an answer for one biome/city related task, you can apply that learning to other tasks too. Or you can post a second question about the next task you need help with after that one. [Be sure to check out past Q&A on generating biomes with noise](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=biome+noise) to get tips even faster.

Comment: While I picked "needs focus" as my vote to close (because your asking about how to set up multiple things & each is its own broad topic), it also qualifies for "needs more details" (because it's unclear *how* you want biomes / cities to affect the terrain & structures). I recommend the edits as suggested in the prior comment.